# Can't connect client to server between 2 PCs socket in java

Tags: java, sockets, server, connection, client

I have a problem, that when I create 2 files (Client.java and Server.java) on the same PC, it works. But when I send the Client.java file to another PC, it doesn't work. I also turn off fire wall but it still doesn't work.

Class Sever.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            System.out.println("loading..");
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6667);
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            String str = dataInputStream.readUTF();
            System.out.println(str);
            dataInputStream.close();
            socket.close();
            System.out.println("end");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Class Client.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("client connecting...");
            byte[] addr = {(byte) 192, (byte) 168, (byte) 9, (byte) 9};
            InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByAddress("lvh", addr);
            Socket socket = new Socket(inetAddress, 6667);
            //socket.setSoTimeout(999999999);
            System.out.println(socket.isConnected());
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dataOutputStream.writeUTF("hello");
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();
            socket.close();
            System.out.println("end");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I send class Client.java to other PC and get error "Connection timed out" like this picture (T_T):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVLgz.png)

I don't how to fix :(( help plz!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to open `DataOutputStream` in both ends before you open `DataInputStream`.

UPDATE: added code

> Server.java

```
package src;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            System.out.println("loading..");
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6667);
            try (Socket socket = serverSocket.accept()) {
                try (DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {
                    try (DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream())) {
                        String str = dataInputStream.readUTF();
                        System.out.println(str);
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("end");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

> Client.java

```
package src;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("client connecting...");
            byte[] addr = {(byte) 127, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 1};
            InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByAddress("localhost", addr);
            try (Socket socket = new Socket(inetAddress, 6667)) {
                //socket.setSoTimeout(999999999);
                System.out.println(socket.isConnected());
                try (DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {
                    try (DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream())) {
                        dataOutputStream.writeUTF("hello");
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("end");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> Server Output

```
loading..
hello
end
```

> Client Output:

```
client connecting...
true
end
```

Hope this helps. :)